# Where does WooCommerce Gift Card plugin actually create the database record?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm not sure if anyone here is familiar with this plugin, but WooCommerce has a plugin called Gift Cards which, as the name implies, creates gift cards.

What I'm trying to do here is to find out where in the code the gift card database record is actually created, so that I can make a call to a Web API and create the gift card on a different system instead. I can't find any `$wpdb->insert` directive, only `$wpdb->update`.

Here's the update code in a method called `function createCard( $giftInformation )`:

```
if (( $_POST['post_title'] == '' ) || isset($giftInformation['rpgc_regen_number']))
{

    if (( $giftInformation['rpgc_regen_number'] == 'yes'))
    {
        $newNumber = apply_filters('rpgc_regen_number', $this->generateNumber());

        $wpdb->update($wpdb->posts, array('post_title' => $newNumber), array('ID' => $_POST['ID']));
        $wpdb->update($wpdb->posts, array('post_name' => $newNumber), array('ID' => $_POST['ID']));
    }
}
```

I should add that I'm totally unfamiliar with WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WooCommerce - Gift Cards](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gift-cards-for-woocommerce/) plugin create a new post in the `wp_posts` table with `post_type => product` and in `wp_postmeta` table create a new rows as

```
meta_key          | meta_value
-------------------------------
_giftcard         | yes
_wpr_allow_reload | no
_wpr_physical_card| no
```

**So basically you can create a simple product with above given meta it will be treated as Gift Card**

So if you want to

Hope this helps!

Comment: So that's a product customers can buy. But once they buy it and check out, where's the actual instance of card stored?

Comment: Sorry I did't get you. You want to know where gift card are stored or you want to know where the order details are saved?

Comment: No I think I get it now. It's just that I find it confusing how everything is a 'post' in WordPress!

Comment: Yes in WP every thing is treated as post with different `post_type`.